# Unity: use native objectiveC and Java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity Project that will be exported to ios and android.

I have a native objectiveC and Android Java code that consists of 2 views (basically a login flow). Both have same logic. What I need to do is the following:

When the app runs, it will run the Native views and code (objectiveC or Java depending on the platform).
Then the user will go through the flow, and once it is completed, I will need to report back to the unity code, and open a scene from it.

Any indications on how can that be achieved, without having to add them after generation of each code?

Because otherwise I would have to put my native code in, every time I generate a new project.

I did some research and came across the "extern" capability, but can it be used to open views from storyboards or android xml files? and trigger logics?
Thank you